# Proxy in front of database servers with AD authentication and auditing possibilities

Tags: sql, database, proxy

Please advice database aware proxy, that can be installed in front of database servers and can provide authentication through Active Directory and log administration queries.

Comment: What database?  I believe they all use proprietary protocols for remote access, so you'd need a specific proxy

Comment: MySQL preferably.

Comment: I believe there is a specific mysql proxy, used mainly for failover but it may handle auth.